# How to prevent cell reusing for the text label?

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I have a table view and in the cell I put text label that indicates likes count. When I load the app, for example, likes count shows 3. But when I scroll down and then return to the top, those 3 becomes a different number.

I know that it's because of cell reusing. How can I save those numbers for each cell and do not update them on scroll?

Images I\ve cached with AlamofireImage, but I do not know what to do with these text labels

Comment: please post relevant code

Comment: You simply set the label's value in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - the cell is just a view onto your data, so reuse shouldn't be a problem, but yes, please post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as a minimum

Answer (score 2):

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath, you can use the indexPath to get the correct value back.
I cannot see your code, so if you are just using a number like 1, 2, 3, 4, etc, you can do 
Example:
`cell.label.text = indexPath.row + 1`

or if you're using an array, you could do the following

```
cell.label.text = array[indexPath.row]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The part you are missing is that you need to use the row index to index into your data.  Obviously we can't see your code, but it sounds like you are not using this.  Generally, you have an array of data, and in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you use the index to lookup the correct data element.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! MyCell

 cell.textLabel.text = "\(likesCount)"

 return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your cell a subclass of UITableViewCell?

Give your cell an *Identifier* (reuse identifier) via IB and then

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCellSubclass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"your_identifier"];
   // .. your code
}
```

And redefine the method in your subclass

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    self.yourCountLabel.text = @"0"; // "reset" value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't prevent it (unless you want to absolutely kill the performance of your application). You embrace it.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, you get a cell that has been used before for a different. So you change everything that you don't want to be the same as for an unknown other row.